# Table view return wrong values when scrolling

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, scroll

The problem is that I have implemented a table view with custom cell from storyboard. Each cell has a button as a selection button which mean whenever I press on a button , it image change. For example, if I press on the button with cell index=0, it image change correctly however when scrolling the table I found other buttons also changed their images! The problem is from the table index path and I spent a lot of time trying to fix it with no result.
Any Solution?

### Thank you

```
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        NSLog(@"index path inside cell = nil %i",(int)indexPath);
    }

    buttonObj=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:40];
   [buttonObj addTarget:self action:@selector(select:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

return cell;

-(void) select:(id)sender{
    UIButton *button=(UIButton *)sender;

    UITableViewCell *clickedCell = (UITableViewCell*)[[sender superview] superview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPathCell = [addFriendTableView indexPathForCell:clickedCell];

    NSLog(@"indexPathCell %i",(int)indexPathCell.row);

        Contacts* selectedContact = [contactsArray objectAtIndex:indexPathCell.row];

        if([self image:button.imageView.image isEqualTo:[UIImage imageNamed:@"addFriend.png"]]==YES){

    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"addFriendPressed.png"] forState(UIControlStateNormal)];
     [selectFriendsArray addObject:selectedContact];
           counter++
        }

        else if( [self image:button.imageView.image isEqualTo:[UIImage imageNamed:@"addFriendPressed.png"]]==YES)
        {
            [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"addFriend.png"] forState:(UIControlStateNormal)];
            counter--;
            [selectFriendsArray removeObject:selectedContact];
            }
```

Comment: It is helpful if you add `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method code in question.

Comment: can you add the cell_for_row code?

Comment: Ok can you please add the code of changing image also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what you are doing is getting same `UIButton` object for every cell. You need to create a separate button for every cell.

Identify this `UIButton` object with unique tag and then select that cell for further.

Create a tag for `UIButton` object. Put below line at top of your view controller class after `#import` statments

```
#define kButtonTag 1000
```

Now set unique tag for each object.

```
 static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        NSLog(@"index path inside cell = nil %i",(int)indexPath);
    }

    // kButtonTag = 1000

     NSInteger btnTag = kButtonTag + indexPath.row;

     [[cell.contentView viewWithTag:btnTag] removeFromSuperview];

     UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    // Set button properties which you required here...
    //....

    [button setTag:[cell viewWithTag:kButtonTag + indexPath.row]];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(select:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
```

In your select method, check for that button tag.

```
- (void) select:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSInteger tag = sender.tag;
    NSInteger index = tag - kButtonTag;

    // Above index is unique index for your cell.
}
```

Hope you will get idea, From this short explanation.

Comment: even if I set the tag in rowForCell, other buttons will also have the same tag because for a reason they have the same index. For example, button at index 0 will have a tag of 1000 but at the same time in my table other buttons are being set to the same tag. In the select method the returned index is correct but the problem is that multiple other buttons also have the same index!

Comment: Button tag 40 is already predefined in the custom cell in storyboard. @kampai

Comment: See here is your issue. You have same button for all cell. Create this button in cellForRow to set dynamic tag.

Comment: All rows are getting me -1000, don't know why :(

Comment: so your using kButtonTag + indexPath.row to set unique tags, What if we have different sections , How will you set unique tags in that case ? because all of the indexPath.row will start repeating from 0 values

Comment: @Max: In that case you can use String concatenation of section row and button index.

Like: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%@%@", kButtonTag, indexPath.section, indexPath.row]`

Answer (score 0):

This is down to cell reuse.  When cells scroll off screen, they are put into a queue to be reused as other cells appear on screen.  The dequeue method pulls them off this queue.  Your problem is that the button image does not get reset when this happens, so if it had previously been changed, it wiil remain.

You need to add some code to your cellForRowAtIndexPath method to set the correct image based on its row.